# How should I mention to this specific location in writing my address

Tags: phrase-request, prepositional-phrases

I am going to write an address. I don't know how should I write it properly!

> *Address:* Forth Floor, No 10, **at the Corner of the x Alley**, Fifth street, Stockholm, Sweden.

[image: Please have a look on this image]

I doubt about the bold part. Does it sound natural to you?

Comment: It depends on *why* you're writing the address. If it's so someone can send *mail* to that address, it's probably a bad idea to even mention the fact of it being on a corner. The specific building identified as **number 10** must be on *either* Fifth Street or Alley X, and the it's the mailman's job to know where **10, Fifth Street** and **10, Alley X** are. You risk your mail going to the wrong one of those two if you confuse the ***postal** address* format with *instructions to help visitors find the premises* (which is normally the only reason you should introduce the *corner* information).

Comment: As I read it, I presume "No. 10" is a room number on the "fourth" floor, in a building that is on the corner of Fifth St. and Alley X. But the building should have a number, like "655 Fifth St." Maybe you can revise your question a bit. Also state if you are looking for a mailing address. If just for directions, what you have should be OK except write "at the corner of X alley *and* Fifth Street".

Comment: @user3169 could you please let me know how should I mention to a specific floor in a specific building number, which is located in a specific street? I need to mention to my building number + my floor in my address at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still not completely clear to me, but as best as I can tell it might be like this if **No. 10** is the building street address:

> Mr. James Smith (for example)
>   Fourth Floor,
>   10 Fifth Street,
>   Stockholm, Sweden

If the **No. 10** is an office number on the Fourth Floor, then:

> Mr. James Smith (for example)
>   Fourth Floor, Room 10,
>   Fifth Street,
>   Stockholm, Sweden

But its unlikely that the address is just "Fifth Street" as there should be a street number.

As for the "at the Corner of" part, you would not put this in a mailing address. Even in directions, there are 2 corners like this so it may go to the wrong place.

Comment: In the first condition, doesn't it require the word 'number' before mentioning number 10? I mean:
Mr. James Smith (for example)
Fourth Floor,
"Number 10", Fifth Street,
Stockholm, Sweden
or you think writing 'number' before '10' is redundant?

Comment: If "10" is the street number address of the building, then no I have never seen "Number" written this way (AmE anyway). But the style varies in different countries. You might look up a Swedish company website and see how they write their address.